# How to upload image or file using cypress-file-upload

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress, image-upload

I am trying to upload an image for E2E testing but could succeed

First of all, I have installed

npm install --save-dev cypress-file-upload

and then using page object model

setting_page.js [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8CCs.png)

```
export class SettingPage {

doc_uploadImage=('#fileDocument')

 uploadimage(){
    cy.get(this.uploadimage).attachFile('D:\Cypress(Projects)\Agorz_Automation_Project\cypress\fixtures\images.jpg')}

}
```

Demo.js

```
import { SettingPage } from "./Pages/setting_page"
import 'cypress-file-upload'

const settingpage = new SettingPage()

it.only('upload file', function () {

settingpage.uploadimage()

})
```

Error message screen is attached here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgcRK.png)

I want to upload an image for testing purposes, you're help will be highly appreciated in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The error statement is clear which means that your given path is invalid.

Could you try moving the image file to your testing project instead like this?

```
.attachFile('images.jpg')}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`cypress-file-upload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload#usage) "recognizes cy.fixture format, so usually this is just a file name." This means that anything that lives in your `cypress/fixture` directory can be referenced by a relative file path.

```js
cy.get(this.uploadimage)
  .attachFile('images.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use the `cypress-file-upload` plugin to be uploading a file in cypress you should use the `attachFile` command provided by the plugin

Using it to upload an image would look something like this

```
const filePath = 'path/to/image.jpg';
cy.get('#fileInput').attachFile(filePath);
```

Also in your code you are trying to use the `attachFile` command on an element you are selecting using `this.uploadimage` but that is a string that corresponds to the selector `#fileDocument` but that is not valid for the `attachFile` command.

here is what you could try to fix this, you could use the `cy.get` command to select the file input, then use the `attachFile` command on it.

```
export class SettingPage {
  doc_uploadImage = '#fileDocument';
  uploadimage() {   cy.get(this.doc_uploadImage).attachFile('D:\Cypress(Projects)\Agorz_Automation_Project\cypress\fixtures\images.jpg');
  }
}
```